# c++ CreateFile() returns 1 (Invalid function) when trying to open device in win 10

Tags: c++, winapi, wdk

I am trying to implement a simple kernel mode driver for process creation monitoring. When I try to open the device using CreateFile() it returns error code 1 (Invalid function). I have added both the driver and user mode controller code below. Please have a look and tell me what i am missing.

UserModeController.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>

using namespace std;

#define MILLISEC 1000

#define IOCTL_ADD_BLAPP CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x801, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA)
#define IOCTL_REM_BLAPP CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x802, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA)

#define MAX_PATH 255

#define CMD_INSTALL     L"/install"
#define CMD_UNINSTALL   L"/uninstall"
#define CMD_START       L"/start"
#define CMD_STOP        L"/stop"
#define CMD_ADD         L"/add"
#define CMD_REMOVE      L"/remove"

#define BL_SERVICE_NAME L"BLDrv"
#define BL_BINARY_PATH  L"c:\\DriverTest\\BLDrv.sys"

#define SYMBOLIC_LINK   L"\\\\.\\BLDev"

HANDLE g_hDeviceHandle  = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

SC_HANDLE g_schSCManager    = NULL;
SC_HANDLE g_schBLDrv        = NULL;

SERVICE_STATUS g_ssBLServStatus;

void PrintHelpMessage();

void InstallDriver();

void UninstallDriver();

void StartDriver();

void StopDriver();

void AddBlacklistApp(WCHAR* inparam);

void RemoveBlacklistApp(WCHAR* inparam);

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{

    if (argc < 2)
        PrintHelpMessage();

    if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_INSTALL))
    {
        InstallDriver();
    }
    else if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_UNINSTALL))
    {
        UninstallDriver();
    }
    else if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_START))
    {
        StartDriver();
    }
    else if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_STOP))
    {
        StopDriver();
    }
    else if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_ADD))
    {
        if (argv[2] != L"")
            AddBlacklistApp(argv[2]);
    }
    else if (!wcscmp(argv[1], CMD_REMOVE))
    {
        if (argv[2] != L"")
            RemoveBlacklistApp(argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Invalid argument." << endl << endl;
        PrintHelpMessage();
    }

    return 0;
}

void PrintHelpMessage()
{
    wcout << CMD_INSTALL << L" - Install blacklist driver." << endl;
    wcout << CMD_UNINSTALL << L" - Uninstall blacklist driver." << endl;
    wcout << CMD_START << L" - Start blacklist driver service." << endl;
    wcout << CMD_STOP << L" - Stop blacklist driver service." << endl;
    wcout << CMD_ADD << L" - Add program to blacklist." << endl;
    wcout << CMD_REMOVE << L" - Remove program from blacklist." << endl;
}

BOOL OpenSCM()
{
    g_schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
        NULL,
        NULL,
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS
    );
    if (g_schSCManager == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open SCManager : " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }   
    else
        return TRUE;
}

BOOL OpenBLServ()
{
    g_schBLDrv = OpenService(
        g_schSCManager,
        BL_SERVICE_NAME,
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
    );
    if (g_schBLDrv == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open BLDrv service : " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
        return TRUE;
}

BOOL OpenDeviceHandle()
{
    g_hDeviceHandle = CreateFile(
        L"\\\\.\\BLDev",
        GENERIC_ALL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM,
        NULL
    );
    if (g_hDeviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create file : " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
        return TRUE;
}

void InstallDriver()
{
    if (g_schSCManager == NULL)
        if (!OpenSCM())
            return;

    g_schBLDrv = CreateService(
        g_schSCManager,
        BL_SERVICE_NAME,
        BL_SERVICE_NAME,
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
        SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        BL_BINARY_PATH,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    if (g_schBLDrv == NULL)
        cout << "Failed to install driver service : " << GetLastError() << endl;
    else
        cout << "BLDrv installed successfully." << endl;
}

void UninstallDriver()
{
    if (g_schSCManager == NULL)
        if (!OpenSCM())
            return;

    if (g_schBLDrv == NULL)
        if (!OpenBLServ())
            return;

    StopDriver();

    if (DeleteService(g_schBLDrv))
        cout << "BLDrv removed successfully." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failed to remove BLDrv : " << GetLastError() << endl;  
}

void StartDriver()
{
    if (g_schSCManager == NULL)
        if (!OpenSCM())
            return;

    if (g_schBLDrv == NULL)
        if (!OpenBLServ())
            return;

    if (StartService(g_schBLDrv, 0, NULL))
    {
        cout << "Starting BLDrv..." << endl;

        while (QueryServiceStatus(g_schBLDrv, &g_ssBLServStatus))
        {
            if (g_ssBLServStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
                break;
            Sleep(2 * MILLISEC);
        }
        cout << "BLDrv started." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to start BLDrv : " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
}

void StopDriver()
{
    if (g_schSCManager == NULL)
        if (!OpenSCM())
            return;

    if (g_schBLDrv == NULL)
        if (!OpenBLServ())
            return;

    if (ControlService(g_schBLDrv, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &g_ssBLServStatus))
    {
        cout << "Stopping BLDrv..." << endl;
        while (QueryServiceStatus(g_schBLDrv, &g_ssBLServStatus))
        {
            if (g_ssBLServStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED)
                break;
            Sleep(2 * MILLISEC);
        }
        cout << "BLDrv stopped." << endl;
    }
}

void AddBlacklistApp(WCHAR* inparam)
{
    if (g_hDeviceHandle == NULL || g_hDeviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        if (!OpenDeviceHandle())
            return;

    ULONG returnLength = 0;

    if (DeviceIoControl(
        g_hDeviceHandle,
        IOCTL_ADD_BLAPP,
        inparam,
        (wcslen(inparam) + 1) * 2,
        NULL,
        0,
        &returnLength,
        0
    ))
        wcout << "Add Blacklist request sent..." << endl;
    else
        wcout << "Failed to send add blacklist request : " << GetLastError << endl;
}

void RemoveBlacklistApp(WCHAR* inparam)
{
    if (g_hDeviceHandle == NULL)
        if (!OpenDeviceHandle())
            return;

    ULONG returnLength = 0;

    if (DeviceIoControl(
        g_hDeviceHandle,
        IOCTL_REM_BLAPP,
        inparam,
        (wcslen(inparam) + 1) * 2,
        NULL,
        0,
        &returnLength,
        0
    ))
        wcout << "Add Blacklist request sent..." << endl;
    else
        wcout << "Failed to send add blacklist request : " << GetLastError << endl;
}
```

driver.c:

```
#include<ntddk.h>
#include<ntstrsafe.h>

#define IOCTL_ADD_BLAPP CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x801, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA)
#define IOCTL_REM_BLAPP CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x802, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA)

#define MAX_PATH 255

ULONG g_NotifyRegistered = FALSE;

PDEVICE_OBJECT g_pDeviceObject;

UNICODE_STRING g_usDeviceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\BLDev");
UNICODE_STRING g_usSymbolicLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\DosDevices\\BLDev");


VOID OnProcessCreation(
    PEPROCESS Process,
    HANDLE ProcessId,
    PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Process);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ProcessId);

    if (CreateInfo == NULL)
        return;
    if (CreateInfo->ImageFileName == NULL || CreateInfo->CommandLine == NULL)
        return;
    if (CreateInfo->ImageFileName->Buffer == NULL || CreateInfo->CommandLine->Buffer == NULL)
        return;

    DbgPrint("ImageFileName : %wZ \n", CreateInfo->ImageFileName);
    DbgPrint("Commandline   : %wZ \n", CreateInfo->CommandLine);
}


VOID Unload(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pDriverObject);

    if (g_NotifyRegistered)
    {
        NTSTATUS status = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(
            OnProcessCreation,
            TRUE
        );
        switch (status)
        {
        case STATUS_SUCCESS:
            DbgPrint("Process creation notification successfully unregistered.\n");
            break;
        case STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            DbgPrint("Invalid parameters.\nFailed to unregister for process creation notification.\n");
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            break;
        case STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED:
            DbgPrint("Access denied.\nFailed to unregister for process creation notification.\n");
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            break;
        }
    }

    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&g_usSymbolicLink);
    IoDeleteDevice(g_pDeviceObject);
    DbgPrint("Driver unloaded.\n");
}


NTSTATUS DispatchDeviceControl(
    PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject,
    PIRP pIrp
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pDeviceObject);
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIOStackLoc = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);

    size_t returnLength = 0;
    WCHAR wzInParam[MAX_PATH] = L"";
    PVOID buffer = pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

    switch (pIOStackLoc->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {
    case IOCTL_ADD_BLAPP:
        wcsncpy(buffer, wzInParam, MAX_PATH);
        returnLength = (wcsnlen(buffer, MAX_PATH) + 1) * 2;
        DbgPrint("Adding : %wZ\n", wzInParam);
        break;
    case IOCTL_REM_BLAPP:
        wcsncpy(buffer, wzInParam, MAX_PATH);
        returnLength = (wcsnlen(buffer, MAX_PATH) + 1) * 2;
        DbgPrint("Removing : %wZ\n", wzInParam);
        break;
    default:
        status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    pIrp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    pIrp->IoStatus.Information = returnLength;
    IoCompleteRequest(
        pIrp,
        IO_NO_INCREMENT
    );

    return status;
}

VOID OnProcessCreation(
    PEPROCESS Process,
    HANDLE ProcessId,
    PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo
);

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
    PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject,
    PUNICODE_STRING pusRegistryPath
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pusRegistryPath);

    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    pDriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;
    pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = DispatchDeviceControl;

    status = IoCreateDevice(
        pDriverObject,
        0,
        &g_usDeviceName,
        FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
        FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN,
        FALSE,
        &g_pDeviceObject
    );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Failed to createDevice.\n");
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }
    else
        DbgPrint("Device created successfully.\n");

    status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(
        &g_usSymbolicLink,
        &g_usDeviceName
    );
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Failed to create symbolic link.\n");
        IoDeleteDevice(g_pDeviceObject);
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }
    else
        DbgPrint("Symbolic link created successfully.\n");

    status = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(
        OnProcessCreation,
        FALSE
    );
    switch (status)
    {
    case STATUS_SUCCESS:
        DbgPrint("Process creation notification successfully registered.\n");
        g_NotifyRegistered = TRUE;
        break;
    case STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER:
        DbgPrint("Invalid parameters.\nFailed to register for process creation notification.\n");
        status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        break;
    case STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED:
        DbgPrint("Access denied.\nFailed to register for process creation notification.\n");
        status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        break;
    }

    DbgPrint("Driver loaded.\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: GENERIC_ALL and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM...: May be system think that you want too much? I saw that is used successfully: GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you not init `IRP_MJ_CREATE` handler. you only do

```
 pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = DispatchDeviceControl;
```

and all. as result was default handler on `IRP_MJ_CREATE` which unconditionally return `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`. this code and returned to user mode. win32 subsystem convert it to `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`

Comment: @SureshKumar BTW for this you probably want to be using IoCreateDeviceSecure so you can add security descriptor for restricting standard rights applications from doing IOCTL with your device driver, and you aren't checking some of your inputs in your kernel-mode driver which can be troublesome later down the road (e.g. rare case maybe for you, but potential Null Pointer Exception, etc.). Basically make sure you always check your inputs as much as possible to prevent bugs which can be exploited (accidentally or on purpose) for denial of service crashes, etc.